# How to get "Turn on WiFi for more Accurate User Location" in iOS 6

Tags: ios, gps, maps

In Apple Maps this Alert comes up when you disable wifi and turn on Cellar Data. How can I implement this Alert in my own Application?

[image]

Comment: @AlexWien turning on WiFi enables network location services, which uses different method for determining of the device location than GPS. Specifically, one of the approaches it uses is WiFi and cell-tower ID lookup table, which in certain situation can improve the precision of the location (particularly in areas with bad GPS signal/low num of satellite visibility)

Comment: it should not be rude, sorry. the point is that in my city (vienna) i never saw an improvement, compared to GPS only (i work full time on GPS applications). In New York (Manhatten) with urban canyons, this might be true.

Comment: @AlexWien I know that wifi improves location services but does the user Know that (I got this alert from Apple Maps so complain to Apple)...

Comment: Thanks @Francis Penov for explaining why the user should connect to wifi

Comment: @AlexWien I am making an Application which is international so places like New York should have wifi ON but maybe not in Vienna.

Comment: i would prefer to read a serious paper measuring the advantage of wifi location. Up to and including ios 5 there was no warning. it also could be motivated that apple wants to collect wifi data for marketing purpose (like google wanted, but was prohibited in some european countries)

Comment: I always thought that wifi helps for the initial location, as the initial GPS start up is so slow (that's why your car sat nav has a start from previous location option)

Comment: Anyone know how to create this popup programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This answer is not exactly achieving your goal.*

This alert message is popped up when Wi-Fi is OFF.

Use [Apple Reachability codes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/) to determine the network type. If not Wi-Fi, prompt this message. However, Reachability can only determine you have Wi-Fi network connectivity, instead of Wi-Fi is ON or OFF.

Location accuracy requires Wi-Fi is ON, but not necessarily it is connected to a Wi-Fi hotspot.

More information:

- there is no SDK to determine Wi-Fi is ON or OFF
- there is no guarantee enabling Wi-Fi will have more accurate GPS
- location accuracy depends on network provider's signal & update frequency

Comment: the Maps App is made by Apple itself. They may implement some undocumented private functions, or even make use of some low-level functions that we developers cannot access to.